# Use Hibernate to set value to uppercase

Tags: java, javascript, html, database

I need to set a value being saved to the DB to uppercase.
My environment is in Java, and I'm using jsp/HMTL/js for front end forms.

I have had suggestions to modify my model's getter/setter but I believe that this may be dangerous seeing as the model may be used in a variety of places, not all of which may want a strictly uppercase value.

Previously I have tried to set the value to uppercase on the web form, using

```
style="text-transform:uppercase"
```

however when the value is saved to the db it retains the lowercase value.

Is there any annotation, or idea someone has on this?

Thanks,
Dearg

Update:

@Vimal Bera I did try this:

```
$('#xyz').on('input', function() {
    $('#xyz').val().toUpperCase();
});
```

But I admit my js experience isn't great, needless to say this did not work.

Comment: Use javascript on client side to convert values to upper case.

Comment: @i486 Oracle is the database

Comment: Is this duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108559/lowercase-annotation-in-hibernate

Answer (score 2):

`text-transform: uppercase` in CSS will display to the client text that is shown as uppercase. From a javascript point of view, the text remains as lowercase. I made a test that can be shown in this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLhwLyq0/2/)**

The way you get the value from an input would be something like

```
var textinput = document.getElementById("yourinput").value;
```

Before submitting to db, you should make sure to do the following on `textinput`:

```
var textinput = document.getElementById("yourinput").value.toUpperCase();
```

---

### Edit

Instead of `.on('input')`, tie your javascript for your `<form>` as the following:

```
<form action="" onsubmit="DoSomethingToInput();">

function DoSomethingToInput() {
    document.getElementById('ppsn').value.toUpperCase();
    return true // this allows the form to submit
}
```

Comment: If you insist on a JavaScript solution, doing the uppercase conversion on the form submit event is the correct way. Performing the conversion on every 'input' event is inefficient, since the DB will not see the text field value until after the submit event, so every intermediate conversion is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, provide an extra getter/setter in the class, map it with an annotation e.g. `@Column(name="DB_Column")`, do something in the getter like `getProperty().toUpperCase();` then mark the *other* property (that you don't want to change for fear of messing up the model) as `@Transient` so Hibernate won't attempt to persist it. Example, let's say catName is your property you want to store in the database:

```
@Transient
public String getCatName(){
    return catName;
}

@Column(name="CatName")
public String getUpperCaseCatName(){
    return getCatName().toUpperCase();
}
```

The solutions calling for client side case manipulating are the wrong choice. You don't want to modify state client side then depend on it on the server side. Always validate user input on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

When you store the value in DB, use UPPER() to convert the case.

Answer (score 0):

You are not talking about changing the value for Display Purposes & hence changing in front-end (JS here) is not the right way.

If you expect the value to be stored in DB as Uppercase - It is better you handle it at the server (Here in Java/Hibernate).

I believe, the simplest way to get this done is to convert the value to Uppercase in the Set method of your @Entity class - like below.

```
public void setCatName(String catName) {
    this.catName= catName.toUpperCase();
}
```

If you change your intention and keep it only for display purposes - You can do that as well in Backend.

Then change the get Method to return upper Case values instead of Set method.

However, it is good practice to do such things at front-end - This to cater to a different use-cases.